# Hibernate Envers inserting null ID in child entities (_aud) when parent entity is removed in @OneToMany relationship with @JoinTable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers, cascading-deletes

I'm using Hibernate version 6.2.4.Final. I have an entity called "Batch":

```
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "batch")
public class Batch extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "batch", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<BatchTechnicalRecord> technicalRecords;
    ...
}
```

I also have the "BatchTechnicalRecord" entity:

```
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "batch_technical_record")
public class BatchTechnicalRecord extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "batch_technical_record_attachment", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_batch_technical_record"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_attachment"))
    private List<Attachment> attachments;
    ...
}
```

And finally, the "BatchTechnicalRecordAttachment" entity that relates "Attachment" to "BatchTechnicalRecord":

```
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "batch_technical_record_attachment")
public class BatchTechnicalRecordAttachment extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_attachment", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_batch_technical_record_attachment_attachment"))
    private Attachment attachment;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_batch_technical_record", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_fk_batch_technical_record_attachment_attachment_batch_technical_record"))
    private BatchTechnicalRecord batchTechnicalRecord;
    ...
}
```

When I try to remove the "Batch", the cascade should remove the associated "BatchTechnicalRecord" entities along with their "BatchTechnicalRecordAttachment" and "Attachment" entities. However, Hibernate is attempting to insert a null ID in the "batch_technical_record_attachment_aud" table for some reason:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" of relation "batch_technical_record_attachment_aud" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, 2052, 2, null, null, null, null, 15, 35).
```

Any help would be appreciated in resolving this issue. Thank you.